# Вместо данных на странице, выводит Not Found?

Tags: node.js, koa.js

У меня постоянно выскакивает ошибка Not Found, хотя данные есть

```
const Koa = require('koa'),
    Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;

const app = new Koa();
const client = new Client();
const url = 'https://www.binance.com/api/v1/klines?interval=1h&limit=24&symbol=BNBBTC';

app.use(async ctx => {
    await client.get(url, (data, response) => {
        ctx.body = JSON.stringify(data);
    });
});

app.listen(3002);
```

Как бы data в консоль у меня выводит данные, а вот на страницу нет

```
[ [ 1534849200000,
    '0.00151270',
    '0.00151480',
    '0.00150620',
    '0.00150950',
    '12238.78000000',
    1534852799999,
    '18.49577488',
    1045,
    '7293.00000000',
    '11.02999493',
    '0' ],
...
]
```

Если вывести что выводит сам этот обработчки

```
let dataParse = client.get(url, (data, response) => {
    return data;
});
console.log(dataParse);
```

То он весь респонс выводит, а как

```
ClientRequest {
  domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  href: 'https://www.binance.com/api/v1/klines?interval=1h&limit=24&symbol=BNBBTC',
  options: 
   { host: 'www.binance.com',
     port: null,
     path: '/api/v1/klines?interval=1h&limit=24&symbol=BNBBTC',
     href: 'https://www.binance.com/api/v1/klines?interval=1h&limit=24&symbol=BNBBTC',
     method: 'GET',
     headers: {} },
  _httpRequest: 
   Writable {
     _writableState: 
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        finalCalled: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        destroyed: false,
        decodeStrings: true,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: true,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     domain: null,
.....
```

Тогда как вывести то что в data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина в том, что [node-rest-client](https://github.com/aacerox/node-rest-client) совсем вообще не умеет в promise.

По этому нужно промисифаить ожидание результата вместо него.

Можно это сделать так, как предлагают на братском [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30112657/how-to-use-bluebird-to-promisify-node-rest-client).

Можно воспользоваться уже готовым решением - [node-rest-client, but with promises](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rest-client-promise).

Можно написать всё самому, например:

```js
const Koa = require('koa');
const Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;

const app = new Koa();
const client = new Client();
const url = 'https://www.binance.com/api/v1/klines?interval=1h&limit=24&symbol=BNBBTC';

app.use(async ctx => {
  const d = await new Promise((resolve) => {
    client.get(url, (data) => resolve(data));
  });
  ctx.body = JSON.stringify(d);
});

app.listen(3002);
```

обрати внимание на то, что тут напрочь отсутствует обработка ошибок, нужно дописать её.

Но лучшим решением, имхо, будет просто заменить node-rest-client на что-то полезное, например, [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).